# Opening a PDF at a specific page

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, pdf

Is it possible unsing the package `hyperref` to open a PDF that was not created using `pdflatex` on a specific page?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374722/latex-hyperref-package-opening-a-target-pdf-at-a-specific-page) solution: `\href{run./FILE.pdf#page.12}{FILE on page 12}`, but that opens the pdf on the first page.

Comment: I use `evince`on Linux.

Comment: instead of `#page.12` have you tried `#page=12`? I have used that in the past and it has worked irrespective of the source file.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by 'recompiling' the pdf document. I made a new `tex`-file that looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{FILE.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Then I linked tot the new pdf with `\href{run./NEWFILE.pdf#page.12}{FILE on page 12}` and it worked.

Comment: If you have the source of the file at hand why did you ask for files that were not created by `pdflatex`?

Comment: I do not have the source file at hand, only the pdf-file.